# Suggestion on deciding the architecture for returning multiple forms from View to Controller ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want some suggestion on how to do the following.

In my ASP.Net MVC application I have a view which can be accessed unauthorized and this view have a registration form now the requirement is that there you can register for multiple people.

So for example if the event can have two persons registered so I need to show two registration form and then the detaisl should be filled and press submit then this whole data should be validated and passed to Controller.

I do not understand how to do this.

Is it possible to have a ViewModel like:

```
public class RegViewModelCollection{
  public List<RegisterViewModel> Collection{get;set}
}
```

?

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Why not just have 2 separate views and in your controller, call the appropriate view. Each view can have its own model.

Comment: it would be not so scalable becase these registration forms can be in the range of 1 - 10 then I would need to have same number of views and controller? and I want to process all data in one submit button.

Comment: You could have a partial view for the form and a back and forward button to go between each person to register. Save the data on button back or forward click, save the form to local storage. Collect them all with a final submit button which sends a collection just as you suggested in your question

Comment: I would use Javascript to render the forms dynamically on the client, store a JSON representation of each form in an array and POST that when *form* is submitted.

Comment: Consider using session state to save values for each form, moving the user to different action methods and views when they go back/forward through the forms. If you must show all the forms on the same view, then consider using one main viewmodel with sub viewmodels and properties.